# Work with images in Jbox2d (java)

Tags: java, jbox2d

I am trying to make the image move rather than a geometric shape in jbox2d.
I dont see the image .

```
BodyDef bodyDef =new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.position.set(100,100);
        bodyDef.type=BodyType.DYNAMIC;
        //texture=TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/small.png"));
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/small.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        bodyDef.userData=img;
```

Comment: JBox2D is based on the Box2D engine, which is a physics engine, nothing relative to something visual. You have to draw the image yourself in the main loop of the program, a method often called render().

Comment: I recommend you to accept helpful answers in your questions, this way you will probably get more help from the community next time.

Comment: Yes I am doing Just that.Its working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JBox2D** is based on the **Box2D** engine, which is a physics engine, nothing relative to something visual. You have to draw the image yourself in the main loop of the program, a method often called `render()`.